# Constant timer in JMeter delays every sample

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter script with N samplers. I intend to add a constant timer of 1000 ms between two samplers. However I noticed it is delaying 1000 ms before every sampler. I'm working with JMeter 2.13 . Am I using it bad or is there any error in the last version of JMeter?

Comment: show a screenshot of your test plan. Where you place the timer in your tree determines what samplers the timer affects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To apply a timer to a single sampler, add the timer as a child element of the sampler. The timer will be applied before the sampler is executed. To apply a timer after a sampler, either add it to the next sampler, or add it as the child of a Test Action Sampler

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if this is new. I have used JMeter for 5 years and never stumbled on this problem.